What do I need to improve on the 128826 ID question to have a better chance of answering it?
What do I need to improve on this question (Interpretation of this learning rate finder plot) to have a better chance of answering it?

I can't speak for the rest of the community, but I personally don't know anything about the cited approach to learning rates, so answering would seem to entail digging into both the paper and the package; I'm not sure there's much else you can do to make it clearer, unless you can summarize what the plots represent and how the method selects the best rate, but then I think that's the content of the question. You might get faster replies by asking on the package's github repo? (Link the two, if you do ask there.)

@BenReiniger thank you, I will try to follow your suggestions. About linking the two, what did you mean?

Just to include a link to the question here in the github Issue, and a link to the Issue in a comment/edit on your question here.

Ah, ok, I got it now, thanks!
